# the number of multisets of positive integers whose sum is n

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, natural-numbers

It is known that the number of ordered $k$-tuples of positive integers who sum to $n$ is equal to $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Given that result, let $p(n)$ denote the number of *unordered* multisets of positive integers whose sum is $n$.  Show  that $$p(n) \ge {\max_{1\le k\le n}} {\frac {\binom{n-1}{k-1}} {k!} }$$

Comment: "whose sum is $n$ is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$".  I have difficulties in reading, I am sorry. What exactly is meant by "any ordered sets"?

Comment: Is the first sentence true? I don't really understand what it means to be honest.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't understand your comment.  The result alluded to in the first sentence is well known and follows immediately from stars-and-bars that there exist $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ different ordered $k$-tuples of positive integers whose sum is $n$.

Comment: Stars and bars gives you multisets though

Comment: @JMoravitz I am sorry, I have difficulties with English. What are "any ordered sets"? Why is it given, if it is well-known?

Comment: @HereToRelax "*Stars and bars gives you multisets though*" Maybe in some interpretations and scenarios, however in this scenario it gives ordered $k$-tuples... noting that order within the tuple matters unlike multisets where order within the multiset does not matter.

Comment: example:
stars and bars solves x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've cleaned up the grammar of the post, hopefully that will help.  The point of the exercise is to use the well known result about the ordered $k$-tuples and use this to talk about and give bounds for [partition numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, now it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrasing: Given positive integers $n$ and $k$ with $n\geq k$, the number of ordered tuples of length $k$ of positive integers whose sum is $n$ is given by $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

This implies the number of undordered tuples of length $k$ is at least $\binom{n-1}{k-1}/k! \quad$ (here by unordered tuple we mean equivalence classes of ordered tuples, where two tuples are similar if they are permutations of each other). This is because each equivalence class has at most $k!$ elements, but can have less (when elements are repeated in a tuple).

We call the number of these unordered tuples $p_k(n)$.

Recall that the partition function $p(n)$ is defined as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n p_k(n)$ so it follows $p(n) \geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}/{k!}$

Please note that "ordered tuples" are mostly just called "tuples".

Comment: why "number of undordered tuples of length k is at least" and not "number of undordered tuples of length k is exactly"?

Comment: because for example, tuples in which all the elements are the same, are only equivalent to themselves.